# Retrieving data from wp_terms table in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to WordPress. I am creating admin panel like WordPress in codeigniter, so I need to understand database table relationships in WordPress. There is a database table `wp_term`s which is used to store categories and tags.

My question or what I want is I want to to display categories and tags by their posts.

e.g. : Suppose I have inserted 4 new posts which are having categories and tags. posts will be stored in `wp_posts` table and categories and tags will be stored in `wp_terms`. So what is a relation between both tables.
Please Help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The categories for both posts and links and the tags for posts are found within the `wp_terms` table.

The core of the WordPress data is the posts. It is stored in the **wp_posts** table. Also Pages and navigation menu items are stored in this table.

Posts are associated with categories and tags from the **wp_terms** table and this association is maintained in the wp_term_relationships table. The association of links to their respective categories are also kept in this table.

For more details between the relations of tables you can see the image below:
[image]

In case if you wants to see the relationship between all the tables then see the image as below:

[image]

To get the more details about the wordpress database tables , you can see the [Link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table_Overview)

e.g. want to to display categories and tags by their posts.

```
<?php $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, $taxonomy, $args ); ?>
```

If you want to use custom query then call `$wpdb` global variable.

```
global $wpdb;
$query= 'write query there' ;
```

Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for answer but still confusion. Can you explain it in detail?

Comment: @ Dipen I am working on codeigniter. I want to create admin panel like wordpress, so I need to understand that.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<?php $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, $taxonomy, $args ); ?>
```